# Decision to use Custom Controller rather than Controller Extension

Tags: controller, controller-extension, custom-controller

I came up with one question which asks me to select two options. 
Question is: When would a developer use a custom controller instead of a controller extension?
Options are:

1. When Visualforce page needs to replace the functionality of standard controller.
2. When Visualforce page does not reference a single primary object.
3. When Visualforce page should not enforce permissions of field-level security
4. When Visualforce page needs to add new actions to a standard controller.

To me correct answer is: 2 and 3. But it is telling the correct answer is 1 and 3. Just wanted to check here if my understanding is wrong.

The reason why I don't want option 1 is that with controller extension we can always replace the default functionality of standard controller like custom save in controller extension.

Comment: Where did you get this question? Could be it is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me answer will be 1 and 3.

Controller extension leverages the **built-in-functionality** of Standard Controller, but overrides one or more actions.

Where as, Custom Controller **replaces** the functionality of Standard Controller without leveraging it.

There is a significant difference in between **leveraging** and **replacing**.

Also, think about that, a class to be recognized as controller extension it must have a constructor that takes a single argument of type ApexPages.StandardController or custom controller you want to **extend**.

For more information, refer [What are Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_def.htm)

Hope, it makes sense!